# Execute Python script inside a given docker-compose container

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I have made a little python script to create a DB and some tables inside a RethinkDB

But now I'm trying to launch this python script inside my `rethink` container launched with `docker-compose`.

This is my docker-compose.yml rethink container config

```
# Rethink DB
rethink:
  image: rethinkdb:latest
  container_name: rethink
  ports:
    - 58080:8080
    - 58015:28015
    - 59015:29015
```

I'm trying to execute the script with after launching my container

```
docker exec -it rethink python src/app/db-install.py
```

But I get this error

> rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: exec: "python": executable file not found in $PATH

Python is not found in me container. Is this possible to execute a python script inside a given container with `docker-compose` or with `docker exec` ?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to have your python script connect to your db wherever it is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rethinkdb image is based on the debian:jessie image :

https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb-dockerfiles/blob/da98484fc73485fe7780546903d01dcbcd931673/jessie/2.3.5/Dockerfile

The debian:jessie image does not come with python installed.

So you will need to create your own Dockerfile, something like :

```
FROM rethinkdb:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python
```

Then change your docker-compose :

```
# Rethink DB
rethink:
  build : .
  container_name: rethink
  ports:
    - 58080:8080
    - 58015:28015
    - 59015:29015
```

`build : .` is the path to your Dockerfile.

Answer (score 3):

First find out if you have `python` executable in the `container`:

```
docker exec -it rethink which python
```

If it exists, Use the `absolute path` provided by `which` command in previous step:

```
docker exec -it rethink /absolute/path/to/python src/app/db-install.py
```

If not, you can convert your `python script` to `bash script`, so you can run it without extra `executables` and `libraries`.

Or you can create a `dockerfile`, use `base image`, and install `python`.

dockerfile:

```
FROM rethinkdb:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python
```

Docker Compose file:

```
rethink:
  build : .
  container_name: rethink
  ports:
    - 58080:8080
    - 58015:28015
    - 59015:29015
```

Answer (score 1):

##### Docker-compose

Assuming that python is installed, try:

```
docker-compose run --rm MY_DOCKER_COMPOSE_SERVICE MY_PYTHON_COMMAND
```

For a start, you might also just go into the shell at first and run a python script from the command prompt.

```
docker-compose run --rm MY_DOCKER_COMPOSE_SERVICE bash
```

In your case, MY_DOCKER_COMPOSE_SERVICE is 'rethink', and that is *not* the container name here, but the name of the service (first line `rethink:`), and *only* the service is run with `docker-compose run`, not the container.

The MY_PYTHON_COMMAND is, in your case of Python2, `python src/app/db-install.py`, but in Python3 it is `python -m src/app/db-install` (without the ".py"), or, if you have Python3 and Python2 installed, `python3 -m src/app/db-install`.

##### Dockerfile

To be able to run this python command, the Python file needs to be *in* the container. Therefore, in your Dockerfile that you need to call with `build: .`, you need to copy your build directory to a directory in the container of your choice

```
COPY $PROJECT_PATH /tmp
```

This `/tmp` will be created in your build directory. If you just write ".", you do not have any subfolder and save it directly in the build directory.

When using `/tmp` as the subfolder, you might write at the end of your Dockerfile:

```
WORKDIR /tmp
```

##### Docker-compose

Or if you do not change the `WORKDIR` from the build ("`.`") context to `/tmp` and you still want to reach `/tmp`, run your Python file like `/tmp/db-install.py`.